# I found how to make table in typescript, but i dont know how to insert it to html code

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I found how to do a html table in typescript (Angular 5), but I do not know how to add it in the html code. The only thing I see is [object HTMLTableElement], I put a table in the html code through {{table}}.

Thanks for help.

My table code :

```
private table: HTMLTableElement;
  private thead: HTMLTableSectionElement;
  private tbody: HTMLTableSectionElement;


  constructor() {
    this.table = document.createElement('table');
    this.thead = <HTMLTableSectionElement> this.table.createTHead();
    this.tbody = <HTMLTableSectionElement> this.table.createTBody();
    var hrow = <HTMLTableRowElement> this.table.tHead.insertRow(0);
    var cell = hrow.insertCell(0);
    cell.innerHTML = "Module ID";
  }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate or post your code.   This question does not have enough context to be answered

Comment: show us your typescript code where you have made your table.

Comment: table code included sorry :)

Comment: Why would you not use angular templating methodology?

Comment: Because I have to be able to edit every table cell by typecript. Something like a graph.

Comment: Try to use datatable. That will be more maintainable.
You can use https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table. Here you will get the ability to edit every cell.

Comment: but you still can create an array of rows of cells' data and use template to map it to the html table. this way any changes to the data will automatically trigger html table update

Comment: I try to make it in html

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure your table is valid, you can use this with Angular :

```
<table [innerHTML]="table"></table>
```

Or (because I see other variables in your code)

```
<table>
  <thead [innerHTML]="thead"></thead>
  <tbody [innerHTML]="tbody"></tobdy>
</table>
```

This is a directive selector for Angular that will set the inner HTML of your tag to the variable you give it.

Comment: Still see [object HTMLTableElement], maybe something wrong with table creation  ?

Comment: Well in this case, probably yes. I'm sorry I can't be of any help for creating arrays in JS/TS, I usually do them in HTML.